# Page loaded event open dialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I have a rails app I am working on that I create a excel spreadsheet that opens in Excel. What I would like to do is create a bootstrap, font-awesome loading spinner icon that shows when I click my "Create Excel" link and hides when the "Open with" dialogue shows. I know I can use the onclick event to do a .show() but what event fires when the "Open with" dialogue shows so that I can do my .hide()?

To add to that, is there an event for when Excel is open if the user chooses the "Do this automatically for files like this from now on."

Here is some of the code I have
My .html.erb page

```
<%= link to '<i class-"fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>'.html_safe, matchsexcel_path(format: :xlsx)%>
```

My model shouldnt be important as it's just your standard model

My controller is standard except for the following

```
respond_to do | format |
format.xlsx
end
```

Then I have my *xlsx.aslsx page which simplified looks like this

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.styles do | s|
wb.add_worksheet(name:"Tab1") do | sheet |
@events.each do | event |
sheet.add_row [event[:item1]]
end
end
end
```

Comment: How are you generating the excel sheet?  Are you doing a form submit to another page, or opening another window tab that returns the excel file for download?  Because if the "Open with" dialog is the browser interface, then that AFAIK is outside the pervue of javascript.

Comment: Some code would help. What have you try?

Comment: Yes the "Open with" dialogue is a browser dialogue not something I have created on my own.

I am using the Rails Gem axlsx_rails, which I basically have a link_to that creates the link that runs my controller that gets my data from the model and runs a .xlsx.axlsx page just like any normal rails .html.erb page but for excel. 

What I had hoped was that there was some way in Javascript or Jquery to determine a pages 200 status to say "yes this page has loaded" fire this event.

Comment: I edited to add some code.